# BLE background processing not working in iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth

I have an application that needs to interact with peripherals when the app enters a suspended or terminated state. I've added the `bluetooth-central` to the `Info.plist` and Capabilities ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFcJ7.png)) but after i connect to a peripheral it doesn't fire any of the delegate methods while running in the background, but as soon as the app enters the foreground the delegate methods are called! I've also set up `CBCenteralManager` state restoration

```
manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: CoreBluetoothRestorationKey])

let ids = [CBUUID(string: ServiceUUID)]
manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(ids, options: nil)

manager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
```

I've been digging around the internet for hours and haven't found anything. Has anyone had a similar situation before? Any tips? Thanks!

edit: code in context:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

 var window: UIWindow?

 let bluetoothManager = CoreBluetoothObserver()

 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

 return true
}
}

class CoreBluetoothObserver: NSObject {

  let manager: CBCentralManager

  override init() {
   manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: CoreBluetoothRestorationKey])
   super.init()
   manager.delegate = self
 }
}
```

the `CoreBlueToothObserver()` initializes `CBCenteralManager` in its init method and sets `self` to its delegate. I would assume `CoreBlueToothObserver()` would be around for the lifetime of the app and not need to be re-initalized in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? or maybe i need to recreate a `CBCenteralManager` and inject it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? Just stumped as to whats happening.

Comment: Can you show your code in context?  This lines of code are fine, but where are you executing them?  Do you set up your CBCentralManager from the AppDelegate?

Comment: @Paulw11 yeah its held as a property in the app delegate

Comment: Can you show the code in context?  You can try rebooting your device. You shouldn't expect any calls when the app is terminated by swiping up but suspended should be fine

Comment: @Paulw11 added some more code!

Comment: You should probably set it up in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. You need to do this in order to restore your CBCentralManager. Specifying the restoration key opts you in to restoration but you still need to write the code to do the restoration.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from @Paulw11 this worked

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

 var window: UIWindow?

 var bluetoothManager: CoreBluetoothObserver!

 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  bluetoothManager = CoreBluetoothObserver()
  return true
 }
}
```

app is now receiving the delegate methods!